# wicked_pdf doesn't work after rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, wicked-pdf

Hi this is not a question, but a solution for a problem :)

I updated rails from `5.1.x` to `5.2.x`, at this new rails version by default updates sprockets from `3.x.x` to `4.x.x` version. Therefor if you are using `wicked_pdf` gem older version you might encounter problem like this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `pathname' for #<Sprockets::Asset:0x0000564070ad65e0>
```

I was using `wicked_pdf` version `1.1.x`. And i didnt found any similar issues. So after some time going trough the code i found out that older wickedpdf gem tries to get `pathname` from the `asset` and `sprockets => 4.0.0` doesn't support `pathname` and uses `filename`

old gem code:

```
  asset ? asset.pathname : File.join(Rails.public_path, source)
```

new gem code:

```
if asset
  # older versions need pathname, Sprockets 4 supports only filename
  asset.respond_to?(:filename) ? asset.filename : asset.pathname
else
  File.join(Rails.public_path, source)
end
```

So in conclusion if you updated your sprockets to v4 you must update your old `wicked_pdf` gem also.